# Regular expression to match [^'] but also \' in string

Tags: python, sql, regex, parsing

I am parsing a .SQL file and try to write it to Mongodb.

I used this regular expression,

```
\((\d+),'([^']+)'(?:,(\d+))(?:,(\d+))(?:,(\d+))\)
```

, it worked for most of the cases.

```
(431532,'Fluorescent_cheese_dyes',0,0,0),(431533,'Christian_Rock_albums',0,0,0),
(431534,'Variety_radio_stations',0,0,0),(431535,'Dean\'s_list',0,0,0),
```

But it did not for the last case about where there is `\'`, as I used `'([^']+)'` to match the string. When I change `'([^']+)'` into `'((?:(?:\')|[^'])+)'`, it will match all the cases in one instance rather than 4. The groups will be like this:

```
1.  431532
2.  Fluorescent_cheese_dyes',0,0,0),(431533,'Christian_Rock_albums',0,0,0),(431534,'Variety_radio_stations',0,0,0),(431535,'Dean\'s_list
3.  0
4.  0
5.  0
```

How can I deal with this, where the second group matches the string with `\'`?

Comment: What are you parsing? I avoid parsing using regular expressions (where possible...)

Comment: I am parsing a sql dump.

Comment: I'm not sure what the format is, but it seems like wrapping it in brackets can create a list of tuples you can `eval` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest replacing `'([^']+)'` with `'(([^']|\\')+)'`.

The string is surrounded by single quotes.  It contains one or more instances of:

- characters except single quotes, or
- single quotes escaped by one backslash

Comment: Thanks! The mistake in my later regex was that I used `\'` rather than `\\'`, which does not match anything correctly.

Comment: `'(([^']|\\')+)'` matches `' \'`

Comment: @sln, that's right, who said it should not?  If the backslash character is only used for escaping quotes and the input string is valid, there will be a matching unescaped single quote, and the greedy `+` will match until that one.

Comment: That's the point, it matches `' \'` when `backslash character is only used for escaping quotes`, there is no closing quote. It may be a moot point if you say the input is valid, but why try to match a so called balanced quote at all then? By using that criteria, `'(.*?)'<pseudo-anchors-here` is actually more valid. For the purpose of escapable delimiters, its hard to imagine the escape itself not being escapable. Usually, closure itself should be as valid as any of the surrounding literals (of which this has many).

Comment: @sin, your opinion is clear.  On the other hand, so is mine.  The specification of what is intended to be parsed should be clear, and should not depend on laziness or not.  The regex I propose is almost deterministic (you'd have to exclude the backslash from the negated class, to make it fully deterministic, which is what I'd recommend if I fully knew what Gi wants to do, e.g., `'(([^'\\]|\\'|\\\\)+)'`).  Lazy repetition, on the other hand, is not as clear, and it leeds to backtracking and performance penalty.

Comment: `'.*?'` doesn't lead to backtracking in this case. There is no where to backtrack. The regex is framed in mostly constants. And I guess is no more vulnerable than an invalid expression that doesn't parse a quoted string correctly. In fact, were it not for the OP's need of the contents, a simple `.*?` would be more than adequate. Performance is not really an issue. If it were, I'd say this `'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'` wins the battle. I didn't really think what I was saying was an opinion, more about facts.

Answer (score 2):

Just use non-greedy `.` (`.+?`)

```
\((\d+),'(.+?)'(?:,(\d+))(?:,(\d+))(?:,(\d+))\)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/zV0lZ1/1

Comment: This will be OK if you match each of these 5-tuples separately.  I believe that you'll run into all sorts of problems if you have a string containing more than one of them and try to match it with `R*`, where `R` is your entire regex.

Comment: @nickie not according to regex101 - you can add as many in a line with a global modifier and it matches them all.

Comment: I think this is a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to account for any escapes within the quotes.

```
 # \((\d+),'((?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*)'(?:,(\d+))(?:,(\d+))(?:,(\d+))\)

 \(
 ( \d+ )                             # (1)
 ,
 '
 (                                   # (2 start)
      (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*
 )                                   # (2 end)
 '
 (?:
      ,
      ( \d+ )                        # (3)
 )
 (?:
      ,
      ( \d+ )                        # (4)
 )
 (?:
      ,
      ( \d+ )                        # (5)
 )
 \)
```